# Is there any class for mouse events for the QgsLayoutManager

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, plugins

I want to get the mouse coordinates when I click or drag my mouse inside the layout window (`QgsLayoutManager`) in QGIS:
after I opened my layout, here is the code:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("Layout22")
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
```

How can I define a function to get my mouse x and y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `QgsLayoutViewTool` which you can sub-class. You can then reimplement and override its methods such as `layoutPressEvent`, `layoutMoveEvent` and `layoutReleaseEvent`.

You can also use the `QgsLayoutViewRectangularRubberBand` class to draw a temporary rectangle item as you click and drag the mouse inside the layout view.

Example code below:

```py
class LayoutToolDrawRect(QgsLayoutViewTool):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view
        self.name = 'Custom Layout Tool'
        QgsLayoutViewTool.__init__(self, self.view, self.name)
        self.rb = QgsLayoutViewRectangularRubberBand(self.view)
        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.dlg = QDialog()
        self.lbl = QLabel(self.dlg)
        self.dlg.setGeometry(75, 150, 500, 75)
        self.dlg.setModal(False)
                
    def layoutPressEvent(self, e):
        self.lbl.setText('Mouse XY: {}, {}'.format(str(e.layoutPoint().x()),
                                                    str(e.layoutPoint().y())))
        self.dlg.show()
        self.rb.start(e.layoutPoint(), Qt.NoModifier)
        
    def layoutMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.lbl.setText('Mouse XY: {}, {}'.format(str(e.layoutPoint().x()),
                                                    str(e.layoutPoint().y())))
        self.rb.update(e.layoutPoint(), Qt.NoModifier)
        
    def layoutReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.rb.finish(e.layoutPoint(), Qt.NoModifier)
        self.dlg.close()
        
    def deactivate(self):
        self.msg.setText('Tool Deactivated')
        self.msg.show()


project = QgsProject.instance()
layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName('Layout22')
open_designer = iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
layout_view = open_designer.view()
layout_tool = LayoutToolDrawRect(layout_view)
layout_view.setTool(layout_tool)
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:** Based on comments below, I understand that you want a way to select different layout tools, then re-activate the custom tool. To do that, you could add a new action to the toolbox on the side of the layout view and connect its 'triggered' signal to a lambda function which sets our custom map tool to the layout view.

Replace the block of code below the `QgsLayoutViewTool` sub-class definition with the block below:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName('Layout22')
open_designer = iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
layout_view = open_designer.view()
layout_tool = LayoutToolDrawRect(layout_view)
layout_window = open_designer.window()
tb = layout_window.findChild(QToolBar, 'mToolsToolbar')
a = QAction('Go', tb)
tb.addAction(a)
a.triggered.connect(lambda: layout_view.setTool(layout_tool))
```

Now, when the layout is opened (via running the code), you should see a new action at the bottom of the 'Toolbox' toolbar like this:

[image]

Clicking on the action will activate our custom layout tool. You can then switch between other tools and the custom tool to your heart's content!

Be aware though, that the action will be removed when you close the layout so you would need to run the code again to open the layout and re-add the action to the toolbar.

Comment: yes sure i've done it :) thanks again 
i wonder if there is any way to draw  a shape for example a rectangle without the tool being deactivated ?

Comment: or is there anyway to reactivate the tool after being deactivated?

Comment: i want to add a new shape  for example add the north arrow the tool got deactivated is there any way to reactivate it

Comment: i found i can override the method: itemFocused 
can i get this item id or name or smthng like that ?

Comment: @Ilyasse Hanafi, I have edited my answer to show you how to add a new action to the layout 'toolbox' toolbar which will activate our custom tool so you can switch back and forth between other tools then re-activate the custom one.